# Evaluate a system in given points in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have

```
f1[x_, y_] := x^2 - 10 x + y^2 + 8;
f2[x_, y_] := x*y^2  + x - 10 y + 8;
f[x_, y_] := {f1[x, y], f2[x, y]} ;
x0 = {0, 0};
```

I want to evaluate `f[x_, y_]` in `x0`, so `f[0, 0]`

I am doing this but does not work, what is the correct way?

```
MatrixForm[f[{x0}]]
```

I get `f[{{0, 0}}]`

but want `{8, 8}` instead

Comment: Either define as f[{x_,y_}] := {f1...} or else leave as it is and use f[Sequence@@x0]

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, it's simpler to use `f @@ x0` directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
In[61]:= f @@ x0

Out[61]= {8, 8}
```

What went wrong? When you evaluate `f[{x0}]` this equals `f[{{0,0}}]`, which doesn't match the  defined pattern for `f`. `f@@x0`, which is shorthand for [`Apply[f,x0]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html), replaces the head of x0 (which internally equals `List[0,0]`, hence its head is `List`), with `f`. You then get `f[0,0]` which matches the argument pattern of `f`. You then get the correct result.